# I'm upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, and the installation is stuck at preparing libc6

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

The installation has been stuck here for about 9 hours now. Also, applications and files won't open, making the computer unusable. Would canceling the upgrade be a bad idea at this point?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, look up on [this blog](http://blog.mattrudge.net/2012/04/26/ubuntu-12-04-lts-upgrade-first-looks). You need to click "terminal" below in your upgrade window and do some action it is waiting for

Comment: Just ran into same issue.. and this got it unstuck.

Comment: the link to the blog does not work

Comment: @begueradj I posted it only in respect to the source where I'd found the answer to this problem. The answer was to click the "terminal" link in a window and to do an action required

Answer (score 0):

Specifically an ncurses window has appeared within the terminal and you need to move through the menus to continue the upgrade.